# Compile error can't find project or library

Tags: excel, ms-access, vb6, vba

I'm not familiar with VB6 , I would like to compile an existing project in a new environment (which mean new desktop) , so do I missed some development tools or references to run the code below ? Because when I running the project it pointed to (Date) .

```
ExcelSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Printed As At " & ls_now
If optCurrent.Value = True Then
    ExcelSheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Year : " & Year(Date)
Else
    ExcelSheet.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Year : " & cboYear.Text
End If
```

Please Help , thousand thanks

Comment: what problem do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a side effect of a missing project reference. Hit the Project->References menu:

[image: VB6 Project References]

Look for anything that is marked as 'MISSING'. Those are the things that need to be installed/registered on your development machine. Once you do so, you'll have to restart VB to reload your project.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing.. I just uncheck that missing(OSSMTP) and it's work.. So do I need to re-download the OSSMTP library ? Because this project has sent email function. btw thank for the help , I was tried download thousand of library to try to solve this. Thank ya ^^

Comment: If you removed the reference and your project still compiles, it's most likely that you don't have any code that uses the library. Otherwise, [http://www.ostrosoft.com/ossmtp.aspx](http://www.ostrosoft.com/ossmtp.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If Date is VB6's `Date` function it needs () after it. In all basics except VB.NET, functions must have brackets, and subs musn't. There is also a `Date` statement that sets the date. That what yours is being interpreted as, but it makes no sense inside another functions parameters.

You could have pressed **F1** and learnt this.

Comment: I think that's excel function not VB6 function.